# SQL Query error driving me crazy!

Tags: sql-server

I'm wondering if anyone can find the mistake in my SQL-Query which I can't seem to find.. Been starring at the same lines of code for like 2 hours and it's driving me nuts!

So, here's the query... (Quite long but hopefully it's readable..) I'm working in VBA connected to the DB hence the ComboBox values and variables.

The error I get says

> Incorrect Syntax near RfD_

So, here it comes. Brace yourselves:

```
SQLString = 
"SELECT 
RfD_.RfD_ID
, RfD_.RfD_Version
, RfD_Status
, RfD_ProjectRef
, RfD_ProjectName
, RfD_StartDate
, RfD_FinishedDate, " & _

"RfD_ActivityName
, Deliverables_.Deliverables_ID
, Deliverables_.Deliverables_Deliverable
, Deliverables_.Deliverables_AcceptanceCriteria
, Deliverables_.Deliverables_Deadline
, Deliverables_.Deliverables_Delivered 
FROM [RFD_New].[dbo].[RfD_] " & _

"Inner join [RFD_New].[dbo].[Deliverables_] 
    on RfD_.RfD_ID = Deliverables_.RfD_ID" & _
    "And RfD_.RfD_Version = Deliverables_.RfD_Version 
where RfD_.RfD_StartDate >= '" & DateFrom & "' 
    and RfD_.RfD_FinishedDate <= '" & DateTo & "' " & _

    "And RfD_.RfD_ID in (
                        SELECT RfD_ID 
                        From [RFD_New].[dbo].[Approval_] 
                        Where Approval_ID = '" & 1 & "' 
                            And (Approval_Name = '" & ComboBox2.value & "' 
                            or Approval_Name = '" & TwistName(ComboBox2.value) & "') " & _

    "And RfD_.RfD_ID in (
                        SELECT RfD_ID 
                        From [RFD_New].[dbo].[RfD_] 
                        Where RfD_ProjectRef = '" & ComboBox1.value & "') "
```

Formatted it a bit to make it more readable but haven't changed anything.
Funny thing is that it works in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio but not in VBA.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if this is your exact code, you forgot to put a space at the end of this line:

```
FROM [RFD_New].[dbo].[RfD_]" & _
```